# How to stop music apps from changing lockscreen

Tags: lock-screens

I am not new to Android, but this is the first thing that has actually stumped me. I noticed my default music app (Xperia Z1ˢ BTW) and Spotify both change my lock screen to the album of whatever I'm listening to. Is there any way to turn this feature off easily? I know my way around android, but I don't know the coding language. This isn't really a problem, but a few album art covers are not exactly school appropriate.

**update**

I have checked the default music app settings, and there is no option to change for this issue either. I'm using Android 5.0.2, and the offensive album art is through Spotify. I also have checked my settings for this, there are no "music" options.

Comment: Did you check your lockscreen settings?

Comment: As an aside, there should be a setting in the concerned app for disabling this feature. You could also delete any *offensive* album art (they are those JPG files stored with your music), in which case a blank screen with music controls will be shown on the lock screen. BTW, what is your Android version?

Comment: I have posted an update in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by **blocking all notifications** from the app. This will prevent Spotify from showing any notifications, including the album art on the lockscreen. The app will still work and play without issue.

Keep in mind this also prevents Spotify from showing the play controls on the lockscreen as well, so if you want to play/pause/next-track/previous-track, you will have to open your phone. I would suggest adding the Spotify widget to your home screen so you have quick access if you need to pause playback quickly.

Thankfully, you can still control the volume with the hardware volume buttons, even if the screen is off/locked, so if you quickly need to stop music you could at least turn the volume down quickly.

Below is quick tutorial. I'm running an older version of Android but you should still have the option to Block All notifications regardless. Your options will just look a little different from mine. Hopefully this works and is sufficient for your needs!

[image: spotify settings] [image: spotify settings 2]
[image: spotify widget]

Comment: Confirmed to work on Android 8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This option isn't implemented in the spotify app yet. This has been posted on the Spotify community forum as a "New Idea" -  [Option to disable album art on lock screen](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Android-Option-to-disable-album-art-on-lock-screen/idi-p/1079160) and is still in the same status.

The only way I could think you can turn the album art on lockscreen off is by completely turning off the notification for Spotify app(`Settings -> Sound & notifications -> App notification -> Spotify -> Block`). But this would hide all the notifications.

Comment: More up-to-date version of the Spotify "idea": https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Android-Music-Disable-Album-Art-on-Lock-Screen-Option/idi-p/1411721

Comment: That is marked duplicate actually in the Spotify site already. Please check properly before posting any useful information. Thanks.

Comment: The "idea" you linked is *inactive*. I'm well aware that the one I linked is a duplicate but it's the one that's active.

Comment: Even if it is marked inactive it will still be considered by spotify. Inactive doesn't mean it's closed or rejected. The number of persons to vote that feature should be atleast 50/year to make that idea active again. So again as I said that a duplicate of the inactive idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Xposed modules for this, I'm also a Spotify user and I hate when whatever OG rapper's explicit album art shows up on my lockscreen.

.

**http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.chaimchaikin.lockscreenalbumartremover**

> Removes full screen Album Art (i.e. when playing music) from the lock screen for Android 5.x

.

**http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.audio.privacy**

> Removes album art and title/artist information from lock screen audio
>   controls (and any other RemoteController) On 5.0 and 5.1 only the
>   album art hiding is effective as the controls are player specific. If
>   you want to hide these too, set a password and configure your phone to
>   hide notifications for your player.

.

I use the second one because I'm on Kitkat. Haven't had any issues.

You'll need a **rooted** phone to install Xposed framework, but it's definitely worth it. (GravityBox/XBlast Tools are the most common add-ons, which let you customize SystemUI -- status bar colors, clock, screen off animation, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a general way of blocking apps from changing your lock screen. Go to Settings -> Device -> Display -> Screen wakes to: and change it from "Lock Screen Notifications" to "Unlock".

Keep in mind that this will block ALL apps from changing your lock screen, not just music apps ...but it seems like only music apps use this feature anyway.

*This is for Android 6.0 but it is probably the same for Android 5.0. The exact path to this setting my be different depending on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

if rooted + edxposed, you can use GravityBox:

lockscreen tweaks -> disable media art

tested on OnePlus 6T OOS 10.3.2 (Android Q)

Comment: Hello Snuupy. Does GravityBox [L] has this setting? OP has mentioned to be using Android 5.

Comment: I don't know but if you're on Lollipop in 2020 you might want to get a new phone :)